# What does "Touchpad mode" change in Flight Control HD?

Tags: mouse, flight-control-hd

[Flight Control HD](http://firemint.com/flight-control-hd-for-steam/), available for Windows and Mac OS X, has a little option called `Touchpad mode`. The in-game help says: *Ensure "Trackpad mode" is enabled in the options for optimized controls.*

Well, "optimized controls" is too vague for me. I want to know (exactly) how it changes the gameplay interaction.

From the few minutes I played with it enabled, I didn't notice any difference.

Comment: If they are "optimized", why is there even the option!?

Comment: probably optimized for playing on a laptop. likely uses more averaged data for the x,y values as it *can* be more difficult to be highly accurate with on a touchpad. however, as all touchpads are not identical it may be that some already perform advanced filtering of the data your finger provides, thus rendering the need for the "Touchpad Mode" in the game un-neccessary. just my two cents

Comment: Flying? Flight stick? I guess you're thinking this is a flight simulator game. It is not.

Comment: yea, i mis-read the title initially and updated my comment. i actually own and love this gem of a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw a path for a plane with *Trackpad mode* **OFF**:

- You must press and hold down the left mouse button while drawing.

In order to draw a path for a plane with *Trackpad mode* **ON**:

- You can either press and hold down the left mouse button while drawing.
- Or you can click on a plane and then move the mouse without any button pressed.

---

In other words:

- *Trackpad mode* **OFF**: Click-and-drag.
- *Trackpad mode* **ON**: Either click-and-drag or click-move-click.